# Show and hide HTML before flash inserting

Tags: jquery, html, flash

the thing i'm searching for my site is something that can show, and after 10 seconds, hide some html.

Exactly is for a games site. I want to show ads during 10 seconds, and after this time, load the .SWF file of the game.

During 10 seconds i want to show the window of the ad in the center of the field where later the game will be displayed. It's like a 700x500px window.

One of the problems is that the ad window maybe 300x200px and i want to put it in the center. It's like i want to make a scene of 10 seconds with tha ad showing like the game is loading.

I beg you to answer in a begginer level, i'm not expert in scripts, just know some html, that's why i'm a bit overwhelmed with the info i found in the net. I would appreciate that you tell me how to write the script or jquery in html in a literally way.

Sorry for being so novice, but i want to learn with the examples you could tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This approach might work work you (requires jQuery).. You can see a working example (without the flash) here: http://jsfiddle.net/qyCX9/

I've tested in IE8, FF 3.8 and Google Chrome.

This is the HTML Markup:

```
<div id="advertisement" class="hidden">your advertisement here</div>
<div id="game">play game!</div>
```

This is the CSS to position the game and ad on top of each other:

```
<style type="text/css">

#advertisement {
    width: 300px; height: 200px;
    background: red;
 }

#game {
    width: 700px; height: 500px;
    background: green;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;   
}

</style>
```

This is the required javascript to position and display the ad, and then to remove it after a set number of seconds..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// get game and ad container
var $game = $('#game'), $advertisement = $('#advertisement');

// position ad container in center of game
$advertisement.css({
    'position' : 'absolute',
    'top'      : ($game.height() - $advertisement.height()) / 2 + $game.scrollTop() + 'px',
    'left'     : ($game.width() - $advertisement.width()) / 2 + $game.scrollLeft() + 'px'
}).removeClass('hidden'); // show ad

// hide advertisement after x seconds..
var seconds = 3;
setTimeout(function () {
    $advertisement.addClass('hidden');
}, 1000 * seconds);

</script>
```

Let me know if this solution works for you!

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. The only thing i don't know how to do, is how to apply the javascript code. Do i have to enclose the code with <script> and </script> and put it before the <body> on the site? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Andrés: Correct, you will need to wrap the javascript within a ```<script></script>``` tag. I've updated my answer to include these tags in the code, as well as the jQuery script. It's best to place this code at the bottom of your page right BEFORE the </body> is closed.

Comment: Don't know what might be going wrong. ¿Maybe there's some kind os problem because i'm using the CMS Wordpress? I added the Jquery script between <body> and </body>. The CSS was added to the stylesheet. And i added the code in the middle of the part of the page that needs it, like this <div id="advertisement" class="hidden">your advertisement here</div>
<div id="game">play game!</div>
But only shows the green background, it didn't appears the red window like in the test site you showed me at http://jsfiddle.net/qyCX9/ .

Comment: You can see the site with all functioning at http://juegos-vestir-maquillar-peluqueria.com/juego-vestir-gato-garfield/juegos-de-vestir-cartoons/ right below the game i added the test windows. What could be? Thanks.

Comment: @Andrés: It looks like the javascript is broken, the console reports that the 'cycle plugin' is having issues. It appears that your WP Theme is already including jQuery (v1.3.2). Just remove the extra ```<script ... src="https://.../ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
``` that I told you to add as it's not needed. Let me know if the problem persists...

Comment: Still not working. I have one jquery-1.3.2.min.js and one jquery.cycle.all.min.js already declared in the WP theme. I removed the extra 1.5.2 that you told me, but still getting the same error. One thing i don't get, is that the 2 js (jquery-1.3.2.min.js and jquery.cycle.all.min.js) are declared before the </head><body> mark. Do i have to put them before, after or it doesn't matter? You can look in http://juegos-vestir-maquillar-peluqueria.com/juego-vestir-gato-garfield/juegos-de-vestir-cartoons/ as an example that is not working. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I tried all combinations, removing the <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script> and others combinations with the ones i have in my theme, like 1.5.2/jquery.min.js and jquery.cycle.all.min.js, but i didn't found any solution. Can you tell what can it be? Thanks.

Comment: The problem now (this page http://juegos-vestir-maquillar-peluqueria.com/juego-vestir-gato-garfield/juegos-de-vestir-cartoons/) is that you need to include jquery before you include script.js (this file contains jquery code which needs to be included after jQuery)

Comment: I tried again many combinations. I have three files and the javascript you wrote me: script.js, jquery-1.3.2.min.js, jquery.cycle.all.min.js and the javascript code you wrote. Right now i have in this order: FIRST jquery-1.3.2.min.js SECOND jquery.cycle.all.min.js THIRD The javascript code you wrote for the ad FOURTH script.js . But as i told you, i tried many positions and removing some of them and adding, and nothing happened. What could be so? Maybe is there any other way to make this work with just javascript or something similar? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to make something like this? I tried many things and nothing worked. Thanks.